# rEFItが起動できない

Tags: linux, macbook

fedoraをインストールしたいですので、rEFItが必要なようです。

http://refit.sourceforge.net/doc/c1s1_install.html
上のリンクに従ってインストールしてみましたが、何度も再起動しても直接OS Xに入ってしまいました。

そして、解決策も探してみました。

```
$ cd /efi/refit
$ ./enable-always.sh
```

上のコマンドを入力しました。でも再起動してもその前と同じ、何も変わりませんでした。

OSのバージョンはOS X Yosemite 10.10.3です。
MacBookのバージョンはMacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015)です。

Answer (score 3):

rEFItは長いことメンテナンスされていないため、特別な理由がなければ後継の[rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)を使うことをおすすめします。

もし、rEFIndを使ってみて何か問題が現れた場合は、少し複雑ですが[EFIブート](http://virtuallyhyper.com/2013/08/install-fedora-19-on-mac-book-pro/)を使うこともできます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。rEFIndを使ってみます。